# Setting up a Polymer in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, polymer

I would like to set up Polymer in App Engine. I would prefer to be using Go to do this if it's even necessary? For data storage I would like to use MongoDB. Does this sounds like a feasible set up for a web-app that acts as a front facing information portal, taking product sales, as well as providing business admin functionality?

Comment: What has Polymer to do with App Engine? Polymer is pure browser/client-side.

Comment: you won't be able to use MongoDB

Comment: Thank you Günter, thank you Paul.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [experimental Go runtime](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/) for App Engine, although it has restrictions, like all App Engine runtimes.  Make sure you're familiar with those restrictions before committing.

You can't run MongoDB on App Engine, but you can of course do so on Compute Engine; in fact it's [available through Click to Deploy](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mongodb/).

You may also like to look at [Managed VMs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/?hl=BG) for more flexibility.

As far as client-side frameworks are concerned, you can use what you like: Polymer, Angular, Bootstrap... it's up to you.